# How do I export just one worksheet in Excel to a single htm file?

Tags: excel, powershell

I'm having trouble saving **one** worksheet from Excel workbook as a **single** .htm file.

I know if I open up Excel, open my workbook, select the worksheet I want, and do a "Save As"  file type .htm it will work.  Every time I code it I get "Hitlist.htm" plus a folder named "Hitlist_files" with all the style sheets, etc.   Unfortunately, in powershell it does the "save as" with all the other data and supplemental files (extra folders, styling specifications, etc.)

Help.  Code below.

```
#Create and get my Excel Obj
$excel = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$excel.visible=$false
$excel.DisplayAlerts=$false
$UserWorkBook = $excel.Workbooks.Open("e:\hitlist\hitlist.xlsx")

#Select first Sheet
$UserWorksheet = $UserWorkBook.Worksheets.Item(1)

#HitList File name and type
$hitlist = "E:\HitList\Hitlist.htm"
$xlHtml = 44

#Save, close, and clean up
#I tried this too...no go - $UserWorkBook.SaveAs($hitlist,$xlHtml)
$UserWorksheet.SaveAs($hitlist,$xlHtml)
$UserWorkBook.close()
$excel.quit()
$excel = $null
```

Comment: To be clear - your last line, _".. even when I change the workbook file to have only one sheet!"_  You're saying that you validated that the `xlsx` workbook has ONLY one sheet, but the HTML output file shows multiple sheets of data instead?

Comment: Meaning: It creates the "Hitlist_files" folder even though I removed all the other sheets.

Comment: That folder, if you look in it, is a reference for the HTML.   It should not have more data than what sheet you're specifying (in position one).  Are you *certain* you're seeing other worksheets, and not the data references for the single one?

Comment: I'm seeing a filelist.xml, a sheet001.htm, stylesheet.css, and a tabstrip.htm.  What I want, is one, self contained .htm file like if you were to do a Save As, htm in Excel and choose just the single worksheet to publish.

Comment: Got it.  Instead of using `44`, try using `45`, please.  If that works for you, please let us know, and I'll post as an answer for you to explain.
_NOTE_: You'll *also* need to have the file extension as a `.mhtml` instead of just an `.html`

Comment: I've suggested an edit to your question, since we further clarified the problem wasn't _actually_ additional worksheets, but instead all of the supplemental files for the `.html` file you generated.

Comment: Grav, great suggestion, but unfortunately the .mhtml file doesn't work for the bigger project I'm working on here.  Part two of this script (maybe I should edit and include that too?) takes that .htm file and embeds it into the body of an email.  Outlook, which, doesn't like frames turns the .mhtml into gobblely gook.

Comment: That's a separate question, sounds like.  That said, one problem solved, yes?  ;)  It would be better to open a new question, link to this one, and explain the new problem.  I'd suggest copy/pasting some of the 'gobbledy gook' or taking a screenshot as well.  Tag me in the new one, and I'll hop on that, for ya.

Comment: It's a single file, but not .htm like I need, so not really.  It's a different can of worms to troubleshoot the .mthml because it packages that one with frames, where as the .htm generated in the application of Excel doing the single worksheet publish does not.  That being said, totally appreciating the help here.

Comment: Given that these additional issues you've mentioned weren't part of the original question... it sounds like you may want to consider revamping your script completely.  Instead of using `SaveAs` within Excel, maybe look at `ConvertTo-HTML` as outlined [here](http://ss64.com/ps/convertto-html.html).  You could pull the data from the spreadsheet into a PowerShell object, and then export to a simple (single) webpage that way.

Comment: The question in the post states exactly what I need to accomplish.  A worksheet in Excel to a single *HTM* file.  I took time to search thoroughly thru the site to find something that would work, wording everything that I need specifically so I wouldn't get slack. Stinks my rep is only 11, otherwise this could have been chatted.

Comment: As noted above, I've used `ConvertFrom-CSV` and also `ConvertTo-HTML` for you below, and rewrote the entire answer.  It works as you expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've adjusted your code to your expectations again, after we clarified some more.  In particular, look at any line denoted with `#changed-grav` for my modifications to your existing code, or the very end (`#added-grav`) for some additional steps I added to fit the exact specs:

(This was tested fully, and appears to be working exactly as you requested - but I did some modifications for my testing, so let me know if I didn't change a value back that you needed)

```
#Create and get my Excel Obj
$excel = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$excel.visible=$false
$excel.DisplayAlerts=$false
$UserWorkBook = $excel.Workbooks.Open("e:\hitlist\hitlist.xlsx")

#Select first Sheet
$UserWorksheet = $UserWorkBook.Worksheets.Item(1)

#HitList File name and type
$hitlistCSV = "e:\hitlist\hitlist.csv" #changed-grav
$hitlistHTML = "e:\hitlist\hitlist.htm" #changed-grav
$xlCSV = 6  #changed-grav

#Save, close, and clean up
$UserWorksheet.SaveAs($hitlistCSV,$xlCSV) #changed-grav
$UserWorkBook.close()
$excel.quit()
$excel = $null

#new functionality, to import the CSV and then export as HTM
#added-grav START
$htmlData = Get-Content $hitlistCSV | ConvertFrom-CSV | ConvertTo-HTML
Set-Content $hitlistHTML $htmlData
Remove-Item $hitlistCSV
#added-grav END
```

Comment: If I had enough rep to upvote you, I would.  Grav, you da man!!!  This is perfect.  Thanks for all the help.  Hope I can return the favor.

Comment: Glad we finally got it isolated and figured out for you.  ;)